# No messages received when using foreachPartition spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am pulling from Kafka using Spark Streaming.  When I use foreachPartition on my RDD I never get any messages received.  If I read the messages from the RDD using a foreach it works fine.  However I need to use the partition function so I can have a socket connection on each executor.

This is code connecting to spark and creating stream

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
    "zookeeper.connect" -> zooKeepers,
    "group.id" -> ("metric-group"),
    "zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms" -> "5000")
  val inputTopic = "threatflow"

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(applicationTitle).set("spark.eventLog.overwrite", "true")

  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))

  val streams = (1 to numberOfStreams) map { _ =>
    KafkaUtils.createStream[String,String,StringDecoder,StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Map(inputTopic -> 1), StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
  }
  val kafkaStream = ssc.union(streams)

  kafkaStream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
    calcVictimsProcess(process, rdd, time.milliseconds)
  }

  ssc.start()
  ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Here is my code that attempts to process the messages using foreachPartition instead of foreach

```
val threats = rdd.map(message => gson.fromJson(message._2.substring(1, message._2.length()), classOf[ThreatflowMessage]))

  threats.flatMap(mapSrcVictim).reduceByKey((a,b) => a + b).foreachPartition{ partition =>
    val socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),4242)
    val writer = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream)
    partition.foreach{ value =>
      val parts = value._1.split("-")
      val put = "put %s %d %d type=%s address=%s unique=%s\n".format("metric", bucket, value._2, parts(0),parts(1),unique)
      Thread.sleep(10000)
    }
    writer.flush()
    socket.close()
  }
```

simply switching this to foreach as I said will work, however this won't work as I need to have sockets created per executor

Comment: foreachRDD ignores the data if there is no action found on the RDD. Try foreachPartition on the each rdd.

Comment: what's the point of that `Thread.sleep(10000)` ??

Comment: also, how do you know you get no messages? The `writer` is never used in the `partition.foreach`, so you don't see your service receiving messages, put they are probably being processed.